# How to fetch Google Places data in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI. Currently struggling with fetching and presenting **photos and places names** to my `List` from **Google Places (Maps) API**. I do know that they provide explanation of how to do it, but since I'm not that experienced yet, i cannot get the code provided just for Swift (**not Swift UI**). Tried to use the method below:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Place]
}

struct Place: Codable {
    var placeId: Int
    var placeName: String
    var placePic: String
    var placeTime: String
    var placePhone: String
    var placeLocation: String
}
  
  
    @State var results = [Place] ()

    var body: some View {

        List(results, id: \.placeId) { item in
            VStack{
                Text(item.placeName)
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
    func loadData(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?parameters") else{

            print("Invalid URL")

            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){data, responce, error in

            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        self.results = decodedResponse.results
                    }

                   
                    return
                }
            }
            print("fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown  error")")

        }.resume()
    }
}
```

## Question:

Is there any ideas of what i do wrong? Because I tried to search for some tutorials on the web, using **SwiftUI**, but haven't found any.

Comment: Please describe what isn't working.

Comment: @MikeTaverne sorry for the late answer. Overall, no data is fetched. As you can see, the is a `Text(item.placeName)`  in the `List`. But I just don't understand what did i do wrong, so places names do not appear in my `List`.. No data is shown.

Comment: Is the code you pasted exactly what you tried? You have this line `self.places = decodedResponse.places` but your array is named `@State var results = [Place] ()`. I don't see how this could compile unless you have another array named `places` somewhere that you're not showing.

Comment: @MikeTaverne edited. I have `results` there, but no data is being fetched.. Still don't understand. May have i named variables  the wrong way?